# Trying to make code that will get two photos turn them into arrays add them together then divide that by 2 and then make a photo with the array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, photo

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


image1 = Image.open(
    "img1")

image2 = Image.open(
    "img2")

array1 = np.asarray(image1)


array2 = np.asarray(image2)


add = np.add(array1, array2)


divi = 2


output = np.divide(add, divi)
final_product = output.astype(int)


Image.fromarray(final_product).save("my.img.numpy.png")
```

Whenever I run this I get the error

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <i8

the problem occurs on line 29

FYI

1. Stackflow would not let me format this as code for some reason.
   2.I am new to python and numpy

Comment: Your code is more simply implemented with `result = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as to change

```
final_product = output.astype(int)
```

to

```
final_product = output.astype(np.uint8)
```

`np.uint8` is the correct `dtype` of an array that came from an image. When you operate a division to the array the `dtype` changes to `float64`

You can check the `dtype` of a numpy array like this:

```
print(arr.dtype)
```

Cheers!